# adding matrix components by using windows form in c#

Tags: c#, matrix

I'm a new C# programmer and I want to write a programs using Windows Forms that can take in an adjacency matrix from a text box and then return the sum of the 1's in the matrix. I'm writing the code for entering the matrix but I don't know how can I sum their components.

```
string s = txtFirstgraph.Text;
string[] words = s.Split(','); 
List<string[]> matrix = new List<string[]>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < words.Count(); i++) 
{
    if (txtFirstedge.Text[i] == '0' || txtFirstedge.Text[i] == '1' )
    {
        string[] temp = words[i].Split(' '); 
        matrix.Add(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("you only can enter 0 or 1 for adjancy matrix please try again");
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, what is `txtFirstEdge`? It isn't defined.

Comment: txtFirstedge is a text box that i enter matrix components on it . it just a condition that matirx only can have 0 or 1 as it's elements

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've improved the spelling and grammar of your question to help people better aid you. Likewise, I indented your code so it's easier to read. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes absolutely no sense without context, but summing the elements in your list should be pretty trivial:

```
var sum=matrix.Sum(w=>w.Sum(q=>Convert.ToInt32(q));
```

A point I would raise is that your adjacency matrix should be of integers, not strings. In fact it could be boolean bit fields if you wanted. But again, your code makes no sense anyway, so maybe you have a reason to do it like that.